# How to connect with credentials from Web Hosting provider

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, web-hosting

Can anyone assist me in connecting via Management Studio using the hostname provided by Godaddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what technology you're using to connect to the database, but a connection string would be something like:

```
Provider = SQLNCLI; -- maybe not necessary, e.g. in C#
  Data Source = hostname;
  Initial Catalog = your database name;
  User ID = username;
  Password = password;
```

Obviously we can't tell you the hostname, database name, username or password...

From Management Studio you would enter your credentials and enter the hostname/IP (and named instance, if relevant) in the Server name box, e.g.:

[image]

...or...

[image]

...or...

[image]

We can't tell you what to enter, because that information is between you and GoDaddy. If you're having a specific problem connecting, we can try to help you figure it out, or at least guide you in what to ask them.

Comment: Hey Aaron,
I knew the above mentioned connection string. I just want to know with  the help of connection string how could we connect to SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: You put the hostname in the server box. If you can't connect then make sure you can ping the server and that it isn't a named instance. You may need to use `IP.ad.dr.ess` or `IP.ad.dr.ess\NamedInstance`. Are you having problems? Could you state what the problem is?

Comment: I can see the images, if you can't see them, I'm sorry I can't help you there either. Maybe your problem is your Internet connection in general?